# Grouping huge amount of rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm tasked with grouping a document with 1500 rows.

[image]

Is there a way to group all of the cells with 150 or 155 inside 1st column but leave other cells untouched?

I tried Subtotal but it sums and adds additional rows that seems to break my document.

Comment: How do you want to group it?? can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to see the rows with 150 or 155 try to filter them out.

As an alternative, you can sort for the first column the group the rows togeter (select rows -> Tab DATA -> Group)